# Running a batch file recurrsively on all sub folders in a directory

Tags: batch-file

So I found this awesome script that is going to help me remove file name spaces but i have like 200+ sub folders that files are in and need to run the command on all sub folders in the directory. This has to be possible right? How can I do it. Right now the commands I know are 'myScript \R C:\somedir\somedir\rootprojectfolder\' but this does not seem to work.

```
:renameNoSpace  [/R]  [FolderPath]
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if /i "%~1"=="/R" (
  set "forOption=%~1 %2"
  set "inPath="
) else (
  set "forOption="
  if "%~1" neq "" (set "inPath=%~1\") else set "inPath="
)
for %forOption% %%F in ("%inPath%* *") do (
  if /i "%~f0" neq "%%~fF" (
    set "folder=%%~dpF"
    set "file=%%~nxF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
    ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myScript /R "C:\somedir\somedir\rootprojectfolder"
```

Uses slashes where indicated and quote the paths to prevent problems with spaces and special characters

Also remember you can not rename a folder if at some point under it there is any file/folder in use

**edited** to adapt to comments - Code updated to handle files AND folders

```
:renameNoSpace  [/R] [FolderPath]
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if /i "%~1"=="/R" (
  set "forOption=%~1 %2"
  set "inPath="
) else (
  set "forOption="
  if "%~1" neq "" (set "inPath=%~1\") else set "inPath="
)
set "doFolders="
:iterate
for %doFolders% %forOption% %%F in ("%inPath%* *") do (
  if /i "%~f0" neq "%%~fF" (
    set "folder=%%~dpF"
    set "file=%%~nxF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
    ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
    endlocal
  )
)
if not defined doFolders ( set "doFolders=/D" & goto :iterate )
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. Would this be able to work on folders as well?

Comment: I ran this new script and it looks like it updated files during the command line scroll but then it looks like the file folders still have spaces when i view the directories. That or it only changed the folders of the last folder in the tree.

Comment: @Omegaman, i pasted the code without removing the `rem` before the `ren` operation. So the code only echoes the operation. I updated it when i realize the problem. Seems you get the code before the update.